# How Can i Get data using GET API In Tabular Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to Display My Complaints Data in the Tabular Form Using the table. i have tried using List it worked. I don't how to Display data in tabular form using Table. When i have tried console log and postman it displays the data contained in the database. I want to get the data in the tabular form. Please help me with a solution.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Table} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Display extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentDidMount();
    this.state = {
      complaints: []
    };
  }    
      componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:80/get/complaints`)
          .then(res => {
            // console.log(res.data)
            // const complaints = res;
            this.setState({ complaints: res.data });
          })
      }
    
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.complaints)
        return (
          // <ul>
          // {this.state.complaints.map(complaints => (
          //   <li key={complaints.id}>{complaints.Regdno}</li>
          // ))}
          //   </ul>
            <Table responsive>
            
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th>Regd_no</th>
      <th>Year Of Study</th>
        <th>Location</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th> Disciplinary Issue</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 
  </Table>
  
  

        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Displaying data in Tabular form from an API response can be done using fixed data table-2. 
It provides a dynamic table with the number of rows as the index of your JSON object.

For more information , you may visit :
http://schrodinger.github.io/fixed-data-table-2/example-object-data.html